# sub query in select clause with hive

Tags: hiveql

I am unable to figure out a way to achieve below functionality through a valid query in Hive. Intention is get the top rated movies in a released in a year based on weighted average.

To be more clear this is what I should be able to do in hive in a single query.

var allMoviesRated = select count(movieid) where year(from_unixtime(unixtime)) = 1997;

select movieid, avg(rating), count(movieid), avg(rating)/allMoviesRated as weighted from 
(select movieid, rating, year(from_unixtime(unixtime)) as year from u_data where u_data_new.year = 1997) u_data_new group by movieid order by weighted desc limit 10;

Comment: I have done it using join. May be an expensive operation but it works.

Answer (score 0):

sadly .. I dnt think there is a way to this in a single query using a subquery to get a count of all movies rated.

You may to write a script which execute 2 queries 
First query one fetch the allMoviesRated and that is stored in a script variable.
Second query is your ranking query to which this value is passed using hiveconf

Thus your script can look like

```
your script.bash or python------------start--------
var allMoviesRated  = os.cmd (hive -S "use db; select count(distinct movieid);")
ranking = os.cmd ( hive -S -hiveconf NUM_MOVIES = allMoviesRated -f ranking_query.hql)  
your script.bash or python------------end--------
```

ranking_query.hql:

```
select movieid, avg(rating), count(movieid), avg(rating)/${hiveconf:NUM_MOVIES }as weighted 
from (
    select movieid, rating, year(from_unixtime(unixtime)) as year 
    from u_data where u_data_new.year = 1997) u_data_new 
group by movieid order by weighted desc limit 10;
```

Comment: Thanks urvish for your efforts.